# don't call ajax if not plugin page

Tags: plugins, ajax

I created a plugin that uses ajax the problem is that the plugin requests are loaded on the whole site and not only on the plugin page I need to call the function only on the plugin page

plugin main code

```
// If this file is called directly, abort.
if ( ! defined( 'WPINC' ) ) {
    die;
}

define("Importer",plugin_basename(__FILE__));
define("PLUGIN_DIR",__DIR__);

require_once PLUGIN_DIR."/vendor/autoload.php";


if(is_admin()){
    $moviewp = new \App\Bootstrap();
}
```

debug error every time I do something on the site using ajax

```
call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'App\Bootstrap' does not have a method 'process_moviewp_like' in C:\xampp\htdocs\clean\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 287
```

how do i exclude site ajax requests and separate them from the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for WordPress's `DOING_AJAX` constant:

```
if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) {
    return;
}
```

...or use the related [`wp_doing_ajax()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_doing_ajax/) function:

```
if ( wp_doing_ajax() ) {
    return;
}
```

However, I'd also double-check to make sure that `App\Bootstrap` has a method named `process_moviewp_like` as well, because that error doesn't look like something that would be limited to AJAX.

Comment: {
        parent::__construct($api_key);
        $this->isMovieWP();
        add_action("admin_menu",[$this,"CreateAdminMenu"]);
        add_action("admin_menu",[$this,"CustomAdminItemMenu"]);
        if(!empty($_POST['action']))
        if($_POST['action']!="")
        if(isset($_POST['action'])){
            $wp_ajax_action = "wp_ajax_".$_POST['action'];
            add_action($wp_ajax_action,[$this,$_POST['action']]);
      }
    }

Comment: Instead of adding code in the comments (where it's all but unreadable), please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/383620/edit) to include it.

Comment: ok, thank you!!